# Connection between 48 ways to acquire Torah and Sefira

Tags: sources-mekorot, torah-study, sefirat-ha-omer, pirke-avot-ethicsof

It seems to be assumed (and I'll give an example in a second) that there is some connection between the 48 ways to acquire Torah (see the so-called sixth chapter of Avot) and the time of the year when we count the omer.
What is the **earliest** source for this idea (or at least the earliest that you know of)?
(48 being almost equal to 49 is not an acceptable answer.)

An example of the 'assumption' is this shiur being given at this time of the year.
http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/876690/rabbi-dovid-gottlieb/48-kinyanei-torah-introduction/
Additionally, I have heard people discussing this in my local synagogues, but can't prove that to you...

Comment: Very related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/71526/do-the-forty-eight-qualities-with-which-torah-is-acquired-correspond-to-the-days

Answer (score 1):

See the Chasam Sofer in the Droshos where he spends a significant amount of time explaining the connection. Also, many seforim note the connection between the 33 kinyan and lag baomer.

Comment: Welcome to mi yodeya. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Where is this in the derashot?

Comment: Also, which 'seforim' do you refer to? Please note my edit to the question - I am looking for as early a source as possible.

Comment: What is 33 kinyan?

Comment: @gt6989b I believe he means the 33rd kinyan